# Data Set is not filling data with newly added column when use SqlDataProvider.Fill Function

Tags: datatables, reporting, sqldatasource

I am using Data Source and Data Table to retrieve Data for Report viewer. Currently I have a requirement to add new column to Data table. Therefore I added new column to the data table. But SqlDataProvider.Fill Function is not filling data for newly added column. I want to know how can I modify the data set when Data or store procedure got changed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GSkp.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
  string queryString =   
      "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";  
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);     
    DataSet customers = new DataSet();  
    adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
```

For more detail check 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter